# Why is my update user model route not working (mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

UPDATE: Posted this a few days ago and I haven't managed to get an answer. Is anybody able to help? Cannot work out why I'm getting this error: 'cannot set property 'username' of null. Seems that the code I'm running to capture current user id isn't working but cannot see where i'm going wrong here.

I can't work out why my update route for my mongodb user model is not working.

So the idea is obviously that the user will be presented with a form with their current user details preloaded and they can then edit the form and it should update the user schema.

Here's my edit profile form:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="user-image-preview" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 user-image-preview"> </div>
<div class ="reg-container-form col-md-8 col-sm-12">
<div class="jumbotron form"><h2><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update profile</h2></div>
<form id="register" action = "/register" method="POST">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type = "text" class = "form-control" value = "<%=currentUser.username%>" name="username"> 
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type = "email" class = "form-control" value = "<%=currentUser.email%>" name="email"> 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <label for="img">Image</label></div>
        <input id="user-image-set" type = "text" class ="form-control" placeholder = "Enter image URL" name = "image">
          <a href="#"><div id="eye-button"><i id="preview-icon" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></a>
</div>

    <button id="submit-login" type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg disabled">Confirm changes</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Form is accessed through the following route:

```
router.get("/profile", function(req, res){
res.render("profile")
})
```

User schema is:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
image: String,
email: String
});
```

So essentially, I want the user to re-enter the params in the input fields, click on confirm and be redirected back to /blogs with the schema having been updated.

I started to write the route but to be honest got lost on the first line. I've created update routes for dynamically generated elements already (comments, blogs) but this seems to be different as with those I am passing through the id etc in the URL. Not sure where to start here...

I've tried using the findUserById method as follows:

```
router.post("/update-user", function(req, res, next){
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.user_id, req.body.user, function  (err,updatedUser){
    if(err){
        res.redirect("/profile")
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.redirect("/blogs");
    }
})
})
```

This code runs fine (as in redirects to /blogs) but doesn't updae the model. So I've tried inserting updatedUser.save():

```
router.post("/update-user", function(req, res, next){
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.user_id, req.body.user, function(err,updatedUser){
    if(err){
        res.redirect("/profile")
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        updatedUser.save();
        res.redirect("/blogs");
    }
})
})
```

This produces the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of null
```

I then tried changing the code to find the current userId as follows (following advice received below):

```
router.post('/update-user',function (req,res,next){
User.findOne({_id: req.body._id},function (err,user){
if(err){
res.redirect("/profile")
} else {
user.username = req.body.username;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.image = req.body.image;
user.save()
}}
)});
```

This produces the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of null
```

Very stuck as to what's going wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to first find the user by Id then just simply pass in the new values.

Updated:

```
    router.post('/update-user',function (req,res,next){

User.findOne({_id: req.body._id},function (err,user){
if(err){
    res.redirect("/profile")
} else {
user.username = req.body.username;
user.email = req.body.email;
user.image = req.body.image;
user.save()
}}
)});
```

I just put it in simple terms, I'm sure you can take care of error handling etc.

Good luck

Comment: Cheers for the reply to this one! How about the form action? Does this look right in my form HTML?

Comment: Yeah , just make sure your action matches your router.post. I'm not sure how you configured your server but you might also need to use urlencoded enctype for your form.

Comment: Hi again, just tried to implement the update route using the findByIdAndUpdate method (see my edit above) but it's throwing an error. To be honest, I'm still a little sketchy on the logic of the update route. I get it with updating comments and other dynamically produced content, but for some reason I'm drawing a bit of a blank when updating a user

Comment: Did you change your form action to match this route? Are you sure you're logged in and have a user object in session?

Comment: Yes, form action is set as <form id="register" action = "/update-user" method="POST"> and I am definitely logged in when trying to access this route. I've added in the original the error message I'm getting

Comment: Ooh, did you require User in the routes file?

Comment: sadly yes ! :( var User  =  require("../models/user");

Comment: Just noticed something, it should be user not User. Try that

Comment: hmmm, but as I've defined var User, wouldn't that mean I need to keep the same case? In any case, just tried changing it (including changing to var user = require("../models/user") and sadly still did not work. I got the same error: user.save is not a function

Comment: i just edited my answer , and thoratically it should work.   BTW , `User = require("../models/user"); ` this line is fine

Comment: Appreciate your help with this! OK so I'm now getting a slightly different error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of null